# Javascript Error: Expected ')'

Tags: javascript

getting this error:

at this line: `totalFundedLabel.push( "label": "Funded");`

JS:

```
var totalFunded =  '${totalFunded}';
var totalUnfunded =  '${totalUnfunded}';

var totalFundedValue = [];
var totalFundedLabel = [];
var totalFundedText = [];

var unFundedValue = [];
var unFundedLabel = [];
var unFundedText = [];

if (totalFunded != null)  
{
totalFundedLabel.push( "label": "Funded");
totalFundedValue.push( "value": <tld-msst:fc-value var="${totalFunded}"/>);
totalFundedText.push( "toolText": "<fmt:formatNumber value='${totalFunded}' type='currency' groupingUsed='true' />");
}


if (totalUnfunded != null)  
{
unFundedLabel.push( "label": "unFunded");
unFundedValue.push( "value": <tld-msst:fc-value var="${totalUnfunded}"/>);
unFundedText.push( "toolText": "<fmt:formatNumber value='${totalUnfunded}' type='currency' groupingUsed='true' />");
 }
```

RENDERED HTML:

```
var totalFunded =  '109321734.06';
var totalUnfunded =  '381234572.79';

var totalFundedValue = [];
var totalFundedLabel = [];
var totalFundedText = [];

var unFundedValue = [];
var unFundedLabel = [];
var unFundedText = [];

if (totalFunded != null)  
{
totalFundedLabel.push( "label": "Funded");
totalFundedValue.push( "value": "109321734.06");
totalFundedText.push( "toolText": "$109,321,734.06");
}


if (totalUnfunded != null)  
{
unFundedLabel.push( "label": "unFunded");
unFundedValue.push( "value": "381234572.79");
unFundedText.push( "toolText": "$381,234,572.79");
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a syntax error because, well, it is.  You probably want:

```
unFundedLabel.push({ label: "unFunded"});
```

The curly braces create an object, with a property called "label". You don't need quotes on the property name if it looks like an identifier (usually).  Looks like all your `.push()` calls are broken in that same way.

Answer (score 0):

You had missing braces `{` & `}` in all the push statements

```
if (totalFunded != null)  
{
totalFundedLabel.push( {"label": "Funded"});
totalFundedValue.push( {"value": <tld-msst:fc-value var="${totalFunded}"/>});
totalFundedText.push( {"toolText": "<fmt:formatNumber value='${totalFunded}' type='currency' groupingUsed='true' />"});
}


if (totalUnfunded != null)  
{
unFundedLabel.push( {"label": "unFunded"});
unFundedValue.push( {"value": <tld-msst:fc-value var="${totalUnfunded}"/>});
unFundedText.push( {"toolText": "<fmt:formatNumber value='${totalUnfunded}' type='currency' groupingUsed='true' />"});
 }
```